# What does "double encoding" mean for a Zoom API URL?

Tags: c#, urlencode, zoom-sdk

In the Zoom Video SDK API documentation found here: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/video-sdk/methods/#operation/sessionStatus it says

> The session's ID. If the ID begins with a / character or contains // characters, you must double-encode the ID value.

The session ID is used in the URL itself, like `/api/sessions/:sessionId/status`. So having a '/' character in the URL does seem like a problem (and in practice, it is). For example, I can get a session id like "4I8wtN3QRkmf4izPrc/2qA==" What's not clear to me is what "double encoding" means here. I've tried:

- URL encoding the session ID
- Base64 encoding the session ID
- "Data" escaping the session ID (from the `Uri` class)

But none of it results in a valid session ID according to Zoom. What am I expected to do to escape the / in the session id?

Note that if I get a session ID without a / in it, my code works perfectly. So the problem is definitley escaping that slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch more searching I found this post:

https://devforum.zoom.us/t/double-encoding-on-uuids/50695

Which shows an ID with the correct "double encoded" version. It had this token `4//M4niJTOCN0Sx/yjwA6w==` with the correct encoding being `4%252F%252FM4niJTOCN0Sx%252FyjwA6w%253D%253D`. Upon inspection, this appeared to be a double URL encoding. When I did:

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sessionId)`

the endpoint responds correctly.

In short, the endpoint expects a double *URL* encoding of any id that contains a `/` (not just begins with or double as the documentation says).